# Recursion - why does python printing this values?

Tags: python, recursion, return

I'm beginner python fan.

Note - **I know, one "return" is missing**.
Purpose of function: sequences with a repeating beginning are given. We don't know how long these "prefixes" are, but we do know there are 7 different ones (the same length). We need to find these prefixes.

However, I am curious how the program works without that word. **Why does the function print sets** (last line) - shouldn't it still stop at else: search (...), go back to the top, and throw out just None when set is long enough?

I also noticed that if I put print between 'else:' and 'search(...)', the sets are printed in the normal order, and if under 'search(...)'- in the reverse order (ie from where the words are longest).

**I would be grateful if someone could explain why it prints at all and in reverse order :)**

```
def search(seq_list, length, position=1):
    seq_set = set()
    for a in seq_list:
        seq_set.add(a[:position])

    if len(seq_set) == length:
        return seq_set

    else:
        search(seq_list, length, position + 1)
        print(seq_set)
```

Comment: Calling ``search`` inside ``search`` doesn't "go back to the top" – it starts a *new* call at the top, while the current call remains at the current state.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't stop. A function doesn't return just because a recursive call returns. `search` finishes, returns its value, then the caller *ignores* that value and continues on to `print(seq_set)`.

It's not clear that it "works", since you are printing the local value of `seq_set`, not the one the recursive call returns and you ignore.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I still don't fully understand why the local value is the longest first and then the shorter it gets. Where does this reverse order of 'seq_set' come from?